# mvvm RETRIEVE data in model or viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am learning `MVVM`. I know model is about my data conceptually. Here is my scenario.

```
database table definition
create table people (SSN varchar(9),first_name varchar(40),last_name varchar(40))
```

In my view `PeopleV.xaml` I defined a `DataGrid` with 3 columns: `SSN`, `FirstName`, `LastName`.

In my model class `PeopleM` I exposed 3 properties: `SSN`, `FirstName`, `LastName`.

In my viewmodel class `PeopleVM` I defined:

```
PersonInfo = new ObservableCollection<PeopleM>();
```

Now I need to perform `select * from people where SSN >= 'xxxxxxxxx'` and put data into a `DataTable`.

My question is where should I do this (defining the `DataTable` and fill it with data), in the model `PeopleM` class or in the viewmodel `PeopleVM` class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Model's are supposed to be dumb data objects that only exist to hold data, so I would not add any kind of data access to that layer.

ViewModels are meant to model the view, and typically would include loading the correct data models for the View to use, however they don't necessarily have to contain the data access code itself.

In most cases, I find it easiest if I put my data access is another layer altogether, and have the ViewModel get the data by interacting with the data access layer.

For example, my ViewModel might have a `SearchCommand` that when clicked would do something like this:

```
void Search(string ssn)
{
    PeopleCollection = PeopleRepository.GetPeopleBySsn(ssn);
}
```

Having a separate layer for data access makes it easier to reuse the data access components, and make the application easier to maintain, update, and test.

Comment: defenders of DDD (not myself) will tell you that having "dumb models" is equivalent to an [Anemic Domain Model](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/07/15/the-anemic-domain-model-pattern/)

Comment: Rachel, the first two paragraphs of your answer is clear to me. But some people say Mdodel includes business layer, data access layer such as entity framework etc. That makes me think that I I should load the data in the Model. The question now is does Model include data access layer?

Comment: @user1794925 There is more than one right ways to do things in programming, so I can't really tell you that absolutely no you should never access your data access layer from your model layer, however personally, my data models never include data access. It *is* possible however that my data access layer will generate my Model layer, such as with Entity Framework, however even then my data models are just dumb objects to hold data, and do not have any functionality of their own beyond basic validation of their own data.

Comment: Rachel, I understand now. Very much appreciate your help:)