# Can i use data source controls in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, devexpress

I'm going to start a new project with WPF+MVVM+EF5

Can i use data source controls in mvvm pattern in ViewModels?

I know that best approach is expose IObservableCollection to view. but for some reasonse i can not use it.

I want to use devepxress's LinqServerMode datasource in my ViewModel to get data from IQuerable and expose it to view.

Is this approach ok with mvvm pattern?
Are this apporaoch an antipattern?

Thanks

Comment: I think that might be better off in the data model and you can expose a method that you can call from the view model

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550242/mvvm-retrieve-data-in-model-or-viewmodel) is a similar question