# Where to fill ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm

I have the following situation:

I have a MySQL Database. I want to read the data from the MySQL table and store it into the `ObservableCollection`. How should I do it in MVVM?

Should I create an extra class beside my Model and ViewModel to deal with stuff like filling the `ObservableCollection`?

I would do create an extra class called `MySQLClass` for example.

`MySQLClass` deals with the MySQL Connection and Queries. Then it fills the `ObservableCollection`..But the `MySQLClass` needs to know about the Model because of the properties.

Is that a problem? is there a proper way on how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550242/mvvm-retrieve-data-in-model-or-viewmodel

Comment: Please, don't force tags into question title, unless it's a natural part of the question. This is not a form, the tag sections makes it clear and visible to people interested and experienced in this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1):

Just because you use MVVM as architectural pattern, doesn't mean you can't use others such as multitier architecture (n-tire architecture) or patterns like repository and/or services.

Also "Model" doesn't mean "data objects", model in MVVM is a layer, not an object. Same for View and ViewModel. Part of "Model" in MVVM also includes data access and persistence, but this do not mean you must put data access into your entities.

Usually you will have models (objects) with fields and methods and business logic. You will have repositories to access, query and persist the data and "services" to coordinate interactions between multiple models or other services.